Sentry CSRF Verification Failed
Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

I am trying a sample python project using this sentry python sdk - https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/
I have sentry deployed using this helm chart - https://github.com/sentry-kubernetes/charts/blob/develop/charts/sentry/values.yaml
Based on this Link here - https://develop.sentry.dev/self-hosted/troubleshooting/
I added this to my helm chart -
config:
sentryConfPy: |
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
"url of the sentry service I created for sentry-web"
]
But I am still getting this error.
